# Excel: Count text occurrences within a Range, when two or more text items are present

Tags: text, excel-formula, count, range, extract

[Excel screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aILO.png)
I have a range (A1:G6) with 5 transactions, one in each row.
Each row has multiple columns with specifics alphabets entered, representing categories of products bought, for e.g. F means fruits, M means Milk, etc.

Now am trying to find the count (in column G) of occurrences of these categories in the range.

To find only one category of product i.e. to find 1 alphabet, it is easy:
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$G$2=B10)+($B$3:$G$3=B10)+($B$4:$G$4=B10)+($B$5:$G$5=B10)+($B$6:$G$6=B10)).

But when we have to find two categories together i.e. to we have to find 2 or more alphabets together (And, not OR) , then I am unable to figure out the code. Could someone help.

Data and expected output is as follows:

| Transction ID | Purchase History of Products |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T01 | C | V | M |  |  |  |
| T02 | P | K | D | M | B | F |
| T03 | M | B | J | V | N |  |
| T04 | P | V | F | M |  |  |
| T05 | V | K | M | F |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Itemset Identification |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| No. | Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 3 | Item 4 | Item 5 | Count |
| 1 | B |  |  |  |  | 2 |
| 2 | C |  |  |  |  | 1 |
| 3 | D |  |  |  |  | 1 |
| 4 | F |  |  |  |  | 3 |
| 5 | J |  |  |  |  | 1 |
| 6 | K |  |  |  |  | 2 |
| 7 | M |  |  |  |  | 5 |
| 8 | N |  |  |  |  | 1 |
| 9 | P |  |  |  |  | 2 |
| 10 | V |  |  |  |  | 4 |
| 11 | B | F |  |  |  | 1 |
| 12 | B | K |  |  |  | 1 |
| 13 | B | M |  |  |  | 2 |
| 14 | B | P |  |  |  | 1 |
| 15 | B | V |  |  |  | 1 |
| 16 | F | K |  |  |  | 2 |
| 17 | F | M |  |  |  | 3 |
| 18 | F | P |  |  |  | 2 |
| 19 | F | V |  |  |  | 2 |
| 20 | K | M |  |  |  | 2 |
| 21 | K | P |  |  |  | 1 |
| 22 | K | V |  |  |  | 1 |
| 23 | M | P |  |  |  | 2 |
| 24 | M | V |  |  |  | 4 |
| 25 | P | V |  |  |  | 1 |
| 25 | B | M | F |  |  | 1 |

Comment: Please provide your sample data as a table via [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) (read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16578424) for an explanation) instead of a screenshot. Then it is much easier to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of sumproduct I use `XMATCH` combined with `BYROW` in this approach:

```
=LET(values,FILTER(B10:E10,B10:E10<>""),
SUM(
    BYROW($B$2:$G$6,LAMBDA(rowrange,
IFERROR(
        N(
          SUM(
              XMATCH(values,rowrange))>0),
        0)))))
```

[image]
It first takes the non-empty values from `B10:E10` and names that `values`.

Than it uses range `B2:G6` to perform a row by row calculation: the row by row range being named `rowrange`.

It then checks for a match of `values` in `rowrange` and sums the match results of all the values in `values`.
If one or more of the `values` has no match it returns an error, therefore the sum would cause an error and the IFERROR returns 0. Otherwise it checks if the sum is greater than 0 (which is the case if no errors where found) and returns 1 *(TRUE converted to number is 1)* for each succesfull row in `rowrange`.

This would spill the result for each row from `rowrange`, but we want to know the total number of rows, so we wrap it in another SUM.

Comment: Thanks P.b for sharing. This solved for the requirement. Thanks a ton. Extremely helpful. Cheers.

Comment: You're welcome.. if it solved your question, please mark it as solved by accepting my answer. (Green tick mark next to question)

Comment: I think it also calculates faster than using SUMPRODUCT

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the count of occurrences of two categories together, you can modify your formula to include multiple conditions in the SUMPRODUCT function.

The syntax for the SUMPRODUCT function is =SUMPRODUCT(array1, array2, ...) . The function multiplies the corresponding elements of the arrays and then sums up the products.

In your case, you want to count the number of cells that contain both category M and category F.. To do this, you can create an array for each category and multiply them together. Then, the resulting array will contain 1s in the cells where both conditions are true, and 0s otherwise. Finally, sum the resulting array to get the total count of occurrences.

Here is an example formula for counting the occurrences of category M (in column B) and category F (in column C):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$6=B10)*($C$2:$C$6=C10))
```

You can check for multiple categories by adding similar conditions like above using "*" between them.

It's also possible to use the COUNTIFS function which is specially made to find occurrences of multiple criteria.

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:B6, "M", C2:C6, "F")
```

This formula counts the number of cells in the range B2:B6 that contain "A" and the number of cells in the range C2:C6 that contain "B"

You need to replace the cell references according to your data.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I had tried these options but it did not work. I have now added data to the question above. Thank you for your time. Appreciate it very much.